# Installing Anaconda on Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, anaconda, raspberry-pi4

I am having issues installing Anaconda on my Raspberry Pi.

When I attempt to install Anaconda I get this message:

Anaconda3-20.02-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 404:/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/conda.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

When I try installing installing mini conda i get this:

ERROR:
cannot execute native linux-armv7l binary, output from 'unman -a' is:
Linux user 5.4.0-1008-raspi #8-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 8 11:13:06 UTC 2020 aarch64 aarch64 aaarch64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're trying to install the 64-bit version but the Raspberry Pi 4 runs on 32-bit. Use the 32-bit versions and you should be okay!

I've recently installed miniconda on my Raspberry Pi 4. I did it using the following commands:

```
# Update linux
sudo yum update -y

# Install python3
sudo yum install -y python3

# Download miniconda installation (32-bit version)
curl "https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh" -o "Miniconda.sh"

# Run miniconda installation
bash ./Miniconda.sh
```

Once you've done this, I would also recommend doing the following **after restarting your terminal**:

```
# Add Raspberry Pi channel for conda installations
conda config --add channels rpi

# Update conda
conda update conda

# Install Spyder IDE
sudo apt-get install spyder3
```

Comment: Though he may be running a 32-bit OS, the Pi4 & Pi3 are both capable of running 64-bit software.

Comment: As of October 2020, Raspian 64-bit is still beta and buggy and discussed here [raspberrypi.org/forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=275370) although an [August release exists](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/raspios_arm64-2020-08-24/), so 32-bit is the best option for GPIO stuff. For homeservers etc. Ubuntu 64-bit (and aarch64 combines binaries) works fine.

Comment: "Anaconda3-20.02-Linux-x86_64": looks like it's 64 bits INTEL/ARM (x86-64)  edition, can't run on a 64 bits ARM.

Comment: @Blithering I can not reproduce your answer. Executing the shell script results in a warning `Your processor does not appear to be an armv7l. This software was sepicically build for the Raspberry Pi 2 running raspbian wheezy` & ultimately fails: `Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh: line 266: /home/user/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.4.3-1/bin/python: No such file or directory ERROR: cannot execute native linux-armv7l binary, output from 'uname -a' is: Linux rpi4 5.4.0-1028-raspi #31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 20 11:30:45 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux`, see https://pastebin.com/R9rhniq7

Comment: @marianoju - looks like you're running the install in sudo when you shouldn't be. Try it again but remove the sudo before ```bash ./Miniconda.sh```

You've installed miniconda in /root/miniconda3:
```Miniconda3 will now be installed into this location: /root/miniconda3```

and then later on it looks for Python in /home/user:
```Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh: line 266: /home/user/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.4.3-1/bin/python: No such file or directory```

Comment: I only tried running it with sudo after installation attempt without failed. @Blithering If you have look at line 29 of my previous paste you will see I specified a different location from `/root/miniconda3`. But FYI here is a [paste executing `bash ./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv71.sh`](https://pastebin.com/1BbSptqU). In the end it's same same, no difference.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is it looks like you're using the wrong shell script to install:

Anaconda3-20.02-Linux-**x86_64**.sh

The Raspberry PI 4 has ARM architecture and is capable of running ARM-64 instructions if you have the 64-bit version of Ubuntu installed.  You can check with `uname -a` and if you see `aarch64` you can run the 64-bit instruction set.

It looks like your distribution is for 32-bit ARM, due to the armv7l output from uname so you would want to look for packages with the armv7l suffix.

There is not very good ARM support right now with a lot of software but hopefully that will change now that Apple is moving to ARM-64.

If Anaconda offers a shell script it should look like this:

For 32-bit ARM:

- Anaconda3-20.02-Linux-**armv7l**.sh
- Anaconda3-20.02-Linux-**aarch32**.sh

For 64-bit ARM:

- Anaconda3-20.02-Linux-**arm64**.sh
- Anaconda3-20.02-Linux-**aarch64**.sh

Answer (score 3):

Conda does not currently provide any `aarch64` prebuilt binaries.

You can instead use `conda-forge`:
https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/#download